# Different outputs between CROSS JOINing of CTE and CROSS JOINing TRANSIENT TABLES

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*(Submitting question on behalf of a Snowflake user)*

---

I am getting incorrect output when using CTE and using CROSS JOINS.

But correct output when creating TRANSIENT TABLES instead of CTEs:

The main culprit is the CLASS CTE

```
WITH
vennDimension AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) -1 AS TIMEPERIOD
         FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 2+1))
  ),
nonVennDimension AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS PRODUCT
         FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 2+1))
  ),
class AS
(
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN MOD(CLASS, 2) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Venn_Group1 , 
CASE WHEN MOD(CLASS, 4) >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Venn_Group2 
     FROM
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS CLASS FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 3 ))        )b
  ),
view_type AS
(
  SELECT * FROM VALUES (1),(2) AS tmp(view_type)
)
SELECT * FROM class
cross join (
SELECT  * FROM (
   SELECT *  FROM
   vennDimension v  --all venn groups plus total
          CROSS JOIN nonVennDimension nv--secondary groups
) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM view_type) c
) a
WHERE PRODUCT=1 AND TIMEPERIOD=0
;
```

**here is the correct output:**

```
CREATE TRANSIENT TABLE 
vennDimension_table AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) -1 AS TIMEPERIOD
         FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 2+1))
  )
  ;

CREATE TRANSIENT TABLE 
nonVennDimension_table AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS PRODUCT
         FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 2+1))
  )
 ;

CREATE TRANSIENT TABLE 
class_table AS
(
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN MOD(CLASS, 2) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Venn_Group1 , 
CASE WHEN MOD(CLASS, 4) >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Venn_Group2 
     FROM
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS CLASS FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 3 ))        )b
  );

CREATE TRANSIENT TABLE 
view_type_table AS
(
  SELECT * FROM VALUES (1),(2) AS tmp(view_type)
)
;

SELECT * FROM  class_table a
CROSS JOIN view_type_table b
CROSS JOIN nonvenndimension_table c
CROSS JOIN venndimension_table d
WHERE PRODUCT = 1 AND TIMEPERIOD=0
;
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any thoughts, recommendations, etc.?

Comment: Your final selects for CTE vs. Transient tables are not the same and  the CTE contains the same alias for 2 different components.  I haven't tried executing your code, but have you tried using the same SELECT in both a CTE vs. a Transient table method?  Once the CTEs are defined, you should be able to write the same select statement.

Comment: @MikeWalton It is confusing that the statements are not exactly the same, but even if you rewrite to something similar, you get consistently different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug, unless we missed some fine writing in the documentation on window functions.

The problem is the `(ORDER BY 1)` in the `class` CTE.  If you change the `1` to any other constant, like `0`, it works.  Go figure!

Comment: Maybe the window function misinterprets the 1 as a column number, but the GENERATOR() table has 0 columns.  It ends up filtering out the non-1 lines from the output for some obscure reason (eg. a bug).